# Flash player 10.0 XML parsing issue

Tags: flash

Guys i have an appplication written in flash, which parses the xml and displays the data.
In the xml there are some unicode characters like <, > etc,. It is working fine in my old system which runs in flash 9. But when i tried to run in my laptop the unicode characters are not appearing. My laptop has flash player 10.0.

Can you guys help me by explaining why this kind of behaviour occurs and what is the remedy?

Sample
"text_widget halign="left"  alt_text="3 X, symbol, negative 18" width="471"
id="widget578781001">3x</i></b>  <</b> ⁻</b>  18</b>]]>

Comment: can you post some code and example xml?

Answer (score 0):

Are the two "systems" different platforms? Has anything about the project changed on either environment?

You should always wrap your content in `<![CDATA[]]>` tags inside XML for Flash.

Comment: I am wrapping my content using  CDATA. yeah they are in different platforms.We have updated the AIR version from 1.5.3 to 2.0